# Is a >> ((sizeof a) * CHAR_BIT) Defined, UB or IDB?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit, bit-shift

1.
Consider the following:

```
unsigned int a, b;

b = a >> ((sizeof a) * CHAR_BIT);

/* or 2nd operand greater than ((sizeof a) * CHAR_BIT) */
```

Is this is defined, undefined behavior or implementation dependent behavior?

2.
Also another sub-question:

In the case `a` is `signed int` and it is shifted less than its bit length, is the signed bit shifting implementation defined or undefined behavior. In both the cases:

1. When shifting right  : `a >> 5`
2. When shifting left   : `a << 5`

**EDIT** question edited

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1.**

From C99 standard, section 6.5.7:

> The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type of the result is
>   that of the promoted left operand. **If the value of the right operand is negative or is
>   greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, *the behavior is undefined*.**

So it's undefined.

**2.**

From the same section:

> The result of `E1 << E2` is `E1` left-shifted `E2` bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros. If `E1` has an unsigned type, the value of the result is `E1` x 2<sup>`E2`</sup>, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. **If `E1` has a signed type and nonnegative value, and `E1` x 2<sup>`E2`</sup> is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.**
>
> The result of `E1 >> E2` is `E1` right-shifted `E2` bit positions. If `E1` has an unsigned type or **if `E1` has a signed type and a nonnegative value, the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of `E1` / 2<sup>`E2`</sup>**. **If `E1` has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is *implementation-defined***.

So for left-shift, it's well-defined if `a` is signed and positive.  It's undefined if `a` is signed and negative.

For right-shift, it's well-defined if `a` is signed and positive.  It's implementation-defined if `a` is signed and negative.

Comment: can you shed some light on the question 2 ?

Comment: @Oil Charlesworth: excellent. I should keep a copy of the standard, its so clearly written. Thank you very much for the answers.

Comment: @phoxis: To be fair, it's not always this explicit and clear!

Comment: Clearest copy of the standard (converted to HTML): http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html